# Add conditional dropdownlist items in ASPX Application (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, conditional-statements

I have a GridView with a asp:dropdownlist

I am able to add dropdown values using rowdatabound.

However what I need to do, is add specific dropdown list values base on the contents of another cell in that row.

So for example if Row(1) and Cell(2) = MAR001, I want the Dropdown values Four, Five and Six

However if Row(1) and Cell(2) <> MAR001, I want the dropdown values One, Two and Three.

Here is my attempt using a loop, however it doesn't target the dropdown values correctly.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1

            Dim Name As String = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text

            If Name = "MAR001" Then
                Dim ddl As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("ddlQuantity")
                Dim numbers As New List(Of String)()
                numbers.Add("Four")
                numbers.Add("Five ")
                numbers.Add("Six")
                ddl.DataSource = numbers
                ddl.DataBind()


            Else
                Dim ddl As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("ddlQuantity")
                Dim numbers As New List(Of String)()
                numbers.Add("One")
                numbers.Add("Two")
                numbers.Add("Three")
                ddl.DataSource = numbers
                ddl.DataBind()
            End If
        Next
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need, but try finding the textbox first and get the text value of that.

**Edit:** i just realized you're looping the rows. you don't have to do that - this is the RowDataBound event, so this code happens for every row.

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

     Dim ddl As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("ddlQuantity")
     Dim numbers As New List(Of String)()

     Dim customerid As String = (e.Row.Cells(2).Text)

     If customerid = "MAR001" Then
         numbers.Add("Four")
         numbers.Add("Five ")
         numbers.Add("Six")
     Else
         numbers.Add("One")
         numbers.Add("Two")
         numbers.Add("Three")
     End If

     ddl.DataSource = numbers
     ddl.DataBind()
 End If
```

Comment: Thanks Wazz, that led me to the answer. You had a mix of C# and VB. I added an edit to your code and have marked as answered